# how to restrict access to other users profile links in buddy press?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have been trying to avoid accessing this specific url which is included under a buddy press plugin profile as :

```
 http://localhost/members/test0/mycred-history/
```

I am using an another plugin MyCred for this.The problem which I am facing is that the above link shows the history of points gained by a user..As it is accessable by every logged in user..Merely I want it to be like in this way that only logged in users can check their own history not to be able to check other members profile history page...And it is working under Buddy Press so please..Any help would be appreciated..!

Simply If I am logged in as "Test1" so I can also check my own follwing link as follows :

```
http://localhost/members/test1/mycred-history/
```

And also I can access other members profile history link also :

```
http://localhost/members/test2/mycred-history/
```

I simply want to restrict access to one's own profile history link only..as it's working as extending plugin namely as MyCrud so it doesn't have that feature by default while Buddy Press already has this feature by default...
So if anyone can just guide me please how to set it for this history page url so that users can't access other users profile history url..!
Would be very appreciated..!
Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the code in MyCred that adds the subnav tab for history. 
In that code, add or change to this:

```
'user_has_access'   => bp_is_my_profile()
```

That removes the tab. But they could still access the history screen by using a direct url. So you need to find the template used for the history screen and add a conditional. Something like:

```
if( ! bp_is_my_profile() ) 
    echo  'Not allowed';
else { 
   // code for creating screen content 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But wouldn't that will just hide the history and instead it will be accessable through direct url still...Would be very appreciated if you can please give solution to that to restrict accessing the history url and instead redirects to the profile page..!

Comment: Did you read the second part of my answer?  The screen would be accessible - but the content would not be created or shown. You could add a redirect call in the template conditional if you prefer.